# Adding HTML email signature to all outgoing email in gsuite using google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I have users in our Gsuite domain who use several email aliases. I need to setup different email signatures depending on the sender email alias. Is there a way to do this without having to pay for external software?
Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged apps script you can create a script where you can use [G Suite Admin SDK](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference) and [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference) to retrieve all the users and then set up a signature for each alias of the user.

This is an example on Apps Script for users: list:

```
/**
 * Lists users in a G Suite domain.
 */
function listUsers() {
  var optionalArgs = {
    customer: 'my_customer',
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'email'
  };
  var response = AdminDirectory.Users.list(optionalArgs);
  var users = response.users;
  if (users && users.length > 0) {
    Logger.log('Users:');
    for (i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
      var user = users[i];
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', user.primaryEmail, user.name.fullName);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No users found.');
  }
}
```

Using [Users: list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list) (from Admin SDK) you will get all the users on your domain, and from that you can use path or update (from [Users.settings.sendAs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs)) to create a signature.

Comment: Thank you very much. For adding the signature what is the workflow? Will the signature be added to every email when sending out or is it a settings field per user?

Comment: Yes, this is used to modify the settings of the alias, this method will not send any message. For that you will have to use the Users.messages: send method.

Comment: Where is the domain wide signature kept? Is the possible to force to add the signature only to outgoing emails?

Comment: The signature is only for outgoing emails, what do you mean with forcing the signature?